# microdata: how to declare several performers in one event?

Tags: events, microdata

I am building a webpage detailing an event.

That event has several people performing, and I would like to list all of the performers using microdata.

Here's what I have:

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" itemscope itemprop="events">
  <span itemprop="name description">EVENT NAME</span>
  <span itemscope itemprop="performer" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <span itemprop="name">PERFORMER 1</span>,
    <span itemprop="name">PERFORMER 2</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Is this valid, or do I have to declare one itemprop="performer" for each performer as follows:

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" itemscope itemprop="events">
  <span itemprop="name description">EVENT NAME</span>
  <span itemscope itemprop="performer" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <span itemprop="name">PERFORMER 1</span>
  </span>
  <span itemscope itemprop="performer" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <span itemprop="name">PERFORMER 2</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: I liked the spelling of the proposed "grammer change" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `http://schema.org/Person` represents exactly *one* person.

Your first example would give *several* names to this single person.

If several `name` values would represent different persons, it wouldn’t be clear to whom additional properties belong:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="name">Alice</span>
  <span itemprop="name">Bob</span>
  <span itemprop="jobTitle">Smith</span>
</div>
```

Who’d be the smith here, Alice or Bob?

So you should use your second example.

Comment: Now that I think about it, can I do this?
`<span itemscope itemprop="performer name" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">PERFORMER 1</span>`

Comment: I’m not sure (I don’t know [Microdata](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/) in detail), but I’d guess: no. In general you can have [several values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9485711/1591669) for one `itemprop` attribute, however, I think they have to belong to the same `itemtype` then. -- You could open a new question for this.

Comment: No you can't. performer is of type Person, name is of type string. You can't combine these two types.

Comment: I have to correct myself, from the standard: [Expected types, text, and URLs](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#schemaorg_expected)
Expected types vs text. When browsing the schema.org types, you will
notice that many properties have "expected types". This means that the value of the property can itself be an embedded item (see section 1d: embedded items). But this is not a requirement—it's fine to include just regular text or a URL.